# Notification Hubs Message Status

Tags: c#, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I have some deployed mobile apps that use a backend Web API (not Mobile Service). I added push notifications support using another vendor. Recently...I wanted to check up on Azure Notification Hubs to see if I can also use them for some specific scenario. I am finding out that the documentation has not been updated for a while ...is it me? Is the notification hub the preferred way to send push notifications in Azure?

I am specifically interested in server-side registration. The doc has a special section about that which is nice but it looks quite complicated. Anyway, is there a way to retrieve the status of a message after I send it? For example, if I send a message to target a specific tag, I would like to know how many devices for each platform (i.e. Android, iOS and Windows) it was delivered to and whether the message is still in enqueue, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I just responded to you at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d420fcc2-7e96-46cc-9dfc-71ea18086b56/notification-hubs-message-status?forum=notificationhubs. Thanks!